# Excel VBA: Find data, loop through multiple worksheets, copy specific range of cells

Tags: macos, vba, excel

I am creating a macro for a file that will be distributed to a team of people; the function is supposed to be able to pull the person's name from a different cell (in Variable B), search for that value in another workbook with multiple sheets (Variable X), and if found copy a specific range of cells from Workbook X to Workbook B.

I am having trouble with the following code:

```
Sub Pull_data_Click()

Dim A As Variant 'defines name from first subroutine
Dim B As Workbook 'defines destination file
Dim X As Workbook 'defines existing report file as source
Dim Destination As Range 'defines destination range of data pulled from report
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

A = Workbooks("filenameB.xlsm").Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value 'constant variable, does not change
Set B = Workbooks("filenameB.xlsm") 'constant variable, does not change
Set X = Workbooks.Open("filenameX.xlsm") 'dependent variable, new name for each new report
Set Destination = Workbooks("filenameB.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Range("B2:S2") 'Range changes for each iteration, rows increase by 1

'check if name is entered
If A = "" Then
MsgBox ("Your name is not visible; please start from the Reference tab.")
B.Worksheets("Reference").Activate
Exit Sub
End If

With X.Worksheets
For Each ws In X.Worksheets
Set rng = Cells.Find(What:=A, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
            ActiveCell.Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$DQ$11").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=A
            Range("A7:CD7").Select
            Selection.Copy
            B.Activate
            Destination.Activate
            Destination.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next ws
End With


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

It is able to compile successfully and has no run-time errors, and when it runs it seems to be looping through the worksheets correctly...but it is pasting the wrong information. Is there anything in this I haven't set up properly?

Comment: 'pasting the wrong information' what information did you expect it to paste? what actually pasted?

Comment: The data you are trying to paste, it's always in one row yes? Range A7 to CD7?

Comment: The information in the range I'm trying to paste is all located in one row, where the value in Column A = Variable A from the sub. After isolating the row with that value, it should copy the values (text and numbers) from Columns A through CD, though the row number may differ. I'm still trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Ohhhh uh then you realize your destination range isn't wide enough to hold your source range? Edit: 82 columns? Yikes XD

Comment: /insert Slowpoke meme

The reason why I had it set like that was because the Macro Editor recorded it when I did it manually...and a large number of the columns are hidden and when the data is filtered out, a manual copy/paste fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT tested. I am taking a stab at what I think you want to do. You're filtering A2 to DQ11 so that's where I set the `find` range. And you're pasting to B2 to S2 and that's only 11 columns wide so that's the range of data I am grabbing. Since you're pasting values (no formatting needed), I am setting the destination range to the source range directly, instead of copy/paste.

Again, untested but I can try to help with errors. I am anticipating range errors XD In short, make backups before you try my code.

Also, not sure if you expect to find data in every sheet. If so, you can't set the destination range as a constant (B2:S2) because the newer data will just overwrite the existing (unless that's what you want). You might consider adding error checking.

Finally, a tangent, but you've been really awesome taking comments and suggestions then doing the research to figure it all out and come back with new questions ^_^

```
Sub Pull_data_Click()    
Dim A As Variant 'defines name from first subroutine
Dim B As Workbook 'defines destination file
Dim X As Workbook 'defines existing report file as source
Dim Destination As Range 'defines destination range of data pulled from report
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Variant
Dim copyRng As Variant
Dim fRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set B = Workbooks("filenameB.xlsm") 'constant variable, does not change
Set X = Workbooks.Open("filenameX.xlsm") 'dependent variable, new name for each new report
'once you set a wordbook, you can use it ^_^
A = B.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value 'constant variable, does not change
Set Destination = B.Worksheets("Input").Range("B2:S2") 'Range changes for each iteration, rows increase by 1

'check if name is entered
If A = "" Then
MsgBox ("Your name is not visible; please start from the Reference tab.")
B.Worksheets("Reference").Activate
Exit Sub
End If


For Each ws In X.Worksheets
with ws.range("A:A")
On Error Resume Next '<---add
Set rng = .Find(What:=A, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

            fRow = rng.Row
            Set copyRng = ws.Range(Cells(fRow, 1), Cells(fRow, 18)) 'i think you want 18 because you're pasting to a range that is 18 cols wide
            Destination = copyRng
end with '<-- move it here            
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'm brand-new at this, but I try to do things well, and if I can't I want to get better.

Your idea to make the destination range = source range works because I only anticipate to find one instance of Variable A in Workbook X. 

I'm getting a runtime error 91 on this section:

`fRow = rng.Row`

Comment: I tried to edit my previous comment: I'm getting a run-time error 1004 (Method 'Find' of object 'Range' failed) on the `Set rng = ws.Range...` section.

I tried removing the portion "ws.Range("A2:DQ11")." before the Find string, and I'm getting a runtime error 91 on this section:

`fRow = rng.Row`

Comment: When I added the Address to that section, it came up with an Invalid Qualifier compile error. I also changed the range to Find to Column A (cells 3-1000), since that's the only column I need the macro to check for the value of Variable A. Didn't help, though. I can change the destination/source ranges later, right now I just need the thing to loop through and pull the right data

Comment: I saw and made those three changes, still ending up with a runtime error 91 on `fRow = rng.Row`. How does an error 91 get resolved?

Comment: Made your changes, it ran through with the `On Error Resume Next` added but didn't paste any data. I removed that line and re-ran it, and the runtime error 91 on `fRow = rng.Row` persists. I'm starting to wonder if I need to focus on just writing the code to find the variable in the first place? I'm not sure, still researching.

Comment: Is that line coming up with the runtime error 91 because fRow isn't "Set"? If so, what do you Set the variable fRow as?

Comment: Really sorry. I am bad at setting ranges as I anticipated XD No, frow isn't working because it's not found on every sheet so rng is empty. The on error resume next fixes that (poorly. There could be better error testing). For now, we need to get ranges to work. I should have more time tomorrow.

Comment: Made a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252879/excel-vba-update-find-data-loop-through-multiple-worksheets-copy-range, had a few ideas that helped? Maybe?