# Excel VBA Update: Find data, loop through multiple worksheets, copy range

Tags: macos, vba, excel

Update to this thread from yesterday: [Excel VBA: Find data, loop through multiple worksheets, copy specific range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32231967/excel-vba-find-data-loop-through-multiple-worksheets-copy-specific-range-of-c/32232962#32232962)

(Special thanks to findwindow for getting me this far!)

I kept getting a runtime 91 error on a certain section, and eventually put in an If/Then statement to skip to the next sheet...but now I'm getting an error 1004 on the line right below it (see below):

```
Sub Pull_data_Click()    
Dim A As Variant 'defines name from first subroutine
Dim B As Workbook 'defines destination file
Dim X As Workbook 'defines existing report file as source
Dim Destination As Range 'defines destination range of data pulled from report
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Variant
Dim copyRng As Variant
Dim fRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set B = Workbooks("filenameB.xlsm") 'constant variable, does not change
Set X = Workbooks.Open("filenameX.xlsm") 'dependent variable, new name for each new report
A = B.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A1").Value 'constant variable, does not change
Set Destination = B.Worksheets("Input").Range("B2:S2") 'Range changes for each iteration, rows increase by 1

'check if name is entered
    If A = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Your name is not visible; please start from the Reference tab.")
    B.Worksheets("Reference").Activate
    Exit Sub
    End If


For Each ws In X.Worksheets
With ws.range("A:A")
Set rng = .Find(What:=A, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If ring Is Nothing Then 'do nothing
    Else
        fRow = rng.Row
        Set copyRng = ws.Range(Cells(fRow, 1), Cells(fRow, 18))
        Destination = copyRng
    End With            
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Yesterday, the error 91 occurred on this:

> fRow = rng.Row

Today, after I put in the If/Then section in that area, I'm getting error 1004 (Method 'Range' of object "_Worksheet' failed) on:

> Set copyRng = ws.Range(Cells(fRow, 1), Cells(fRow, 18))

The syntax is working and it seems to be looking in the correct workbook, but I'm not sure if it's getting stuck because the variable I'm searching for (Variable A) isn't present on the first sheet. Any ideas?

Comment: Yea Bruce's got it. Nice error check.

Comment: We're getting closer, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for?
There was an end if missing? You can do the copy in a single line. See below ...

```
For Each ws In X.Worksheets
    With ws.Range("A:A")
        Set rng = .Find(What:=A, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If rng Is Nothing Then 'do nothing
          Else
          fRow = rng.Row
           ws.Range("A" + CStr(fRow) + ":" + "R" + CStr(fRow)).Copy Destination:=Destination
        End If
    End With
Next ws
```

Comment: IT WORKS!

I have to fix the range because it's not 100% what I needed, but I know exactly how to do that.

Thank you, as well as BruceWayne and findwindow from the other threads!

Comment: Nice! Although, as I mention in my answer, I would possibly flip the `If rng is Nothing then [implicit DO NOTHING, END IF]` to `If Not rng is Nothing Then fRow = ...`. Unless of course there's a reason - I personally just don't like `If` statements that "hang open" if they can be avoided.

Comment: That's a fair point to make. I'll keep it in mind as I tweak the code. FYI, this is a major breakthrough for me as it provides a proof of concept for something I've been working on for months. Y'all are the best!

Answer (score 2):

A quick note - and possibly the solution:

I see you're working with multiple worksheets - this is fine, just remember to be hyper vigilant in setting ranges.

For your `Set copyRng`, you correctly specify `ws.Range`, but you also need to do that for the `Cells()`.  There are two fixes, use this:
`Set copyRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, 1), ws.Cells(fRow, 18))`

Or, use `With` (my personal preference):

```
With ws
    Set copyRng = .Range(.Cells(fRow,1),.Cells(fRow,18))
End with
```

In the `With` case, you'll notice you can just use a decimal as a placeholder for whatever your `With __` is.  (I like `With`, because if your worksheet variable is long, or you're just using the actual name, having to repeat that in `thisIsMyWorksheet.Range(thisismyWorksheet.Cells(1,1),thisismyworksheet.cells(...` can get quite long).

If that doesn't do the trick, let me know. I've had spreadsheets hang up when I forget to explicitly give the `Cells()` worksheet, after giving the `Range` one.

Edit: Per your comment,
First, it looks like there's a typo in your `If ring Is Nothing` - should be `If rng Is Nothing Then`.  I don't like that "If (TRUE) Then [implicitly do nothing]".

Try this instead, for the worksheet loop:

```
For Each ws In X.Worksheets
    With ws.Range("A:A")
        Set rng = .Find(What:=A, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            fRow = rng.Row
            Set copyRng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fRow, 1), ws.Cells(fRow, 18))
            Destination.Value = copyRng.Value
        End With
    Next ws

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This did resolve the runtime errors. Thanks! However, the macro runs all the way through without copying any data to the destination range, and I can't tell if it's actually looping through each worksheet in the Variable X workbook. 

The Variable X workbook has macros, so whenever it opens up I have to click the box to 'Enable Macros', which takes it to the default worksheet...does that matter?